# In slick carousel, i want my center slider image to have a margin-top

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I have three images to be shown on a page and I want the image which comes in center by sliding should have margin-top that means my center image should be little down then the other two images which are on both the sides of the image.

Comment: We'll probably need to see some code. Do you have a min-height set on your slides?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using centerMode:true, there's a .slick-center class applied to the element in the middle. You can create a css rule like:

```
.slick-center {
   margin-top:0.5%;
 }
```

Comment: I actually didn't even consider `centerMode:`'s classes. +1 for responsive scalability :)

Comment: I applied it but after 5-6 slides the middle element first is at its original position and then takes the margin (start with up and then comes down).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `centerMode:true` on, and for some reason you can't enable it, you can always target the `.slick-current` class (which will be the first of the three slides that are showing, and then target it's adjacent sibling like this:

```
.slick-current + .slick-slide {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

However, if both options are available to you, I would suggest going with Tutch's answer as it scales better in cases where you might increase/decrease slide counts dynamically.

Comment: I applied it but after 5-6 slides the middle element first is at its original position and then takes the margin (start with up and then comes down).